# How to test library functions that work on storage string[]

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have a library for string array handling functions that has functions like:

`function deleteAt(string[] storage, uint pos) {...}`

It's meant to be run inside a contract which has a state var of string[], and it works as expected when run inside a the contract.

But I'm trying to write a unit test for it and I can't figure out how.

For starters, I can't figure out how to call it from javascript, other than

```
   it(`removes an array element`, ()=> {
        const ArrayLibrary = await ethers.getContractFactory("ArrayLibrary");
        const arrayLibrary = await ArrayLibrary.deploy();
        let lib = await arrayLibrary.deployed();
        let ar = ["Apple", "Banana", "Peach];
        
        let result = await lib.deleteAt(1);  //. <== fails
    }
```

This fails with `TypeError lib.deleteAt is not a function`, and even if it worked I'm not really sure what I could do with `result` which I guess would be a tx receipt or something.

Short of creating a separate contract specifically to test this function on a storage array, is there some way I can test this from javascript - mocha/chai using hardhat?

I do know the problem is not with the lib instance of the contract.  Other function (which work on string[] memory params passed in) work as expected in test, and a test contract which calls `myStorageArray.deleteAt(1)` works just fine.

In case useful, here's the deleteAt function defined inside library `ArrayLibrary`

```
/** @dev Deletes item from storage array at position pos, keeps order */
    function deleteAt(string[] storage ar, uint pos) public {
        uint len = ar.length;
        for(uint i = pos; i<len-1; i++) {
            ar[i]=ar[i+1];
        }
        ar.pop();
    }
```